# Not able to send Email through Jenkins

Tags: java, email, jenkins, smtp

I am trying to configure auto email generation through jenkins, but I am getting an error:

```
SMTP Server: smtp.server.gmail,SMTP Port: 465,Charset: UTF-8
```

It says:

```
Failed to send out e-mail

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g2sm4020944pfc.130 - gsmtp
```

Note: I have already enabled my POP and IMAP settings in my Gmail account.

Comment: It looks like you configured Jenkins to use Gmail's SMTP server but haven't provided credentials. Which version of Jenkins are you running? Who did the mailing configuration? Also, IMAP and POP3 are protocols to fetch emails from your mail server, SMTP is used for sending emails.

Comment: Luckily its working fine now after changed less secure app settings= Turn ON.

Comment: Strange, but happy to hear it's working.